# Swift: How to add a popup screen with label when a button is pressed in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The attached image is a TableviewCell in a tableview. When the user clicks on the "i" button, I want to show a popup screen, where I need to display certain text. Can someone help me how to create a view and display text.

I have tried using [NMPopUpView](https://github.com/psy2k/NMPopUpView), but I only works on normal view, but not on table view. Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: You can use UIAlertView

Comment: @UmairAfzal UIAlertView is deprecated. You'll need to use  UIAlertController instead.

Comment: If it is working on the normal view. Try passing the cell.contentView to it.

Comment: Its should be able to work for all kinds of view. Can you please show the codesnippet, of where you've implemented it?

Comment: Check my answer, and let me know if it works for you. If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a popover to go about this. Connect the "i" button to a view controller and make that a popover. For details on how exactly to use popovers see [here](https://makeapppie.com/tag/popover-in-swift/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a xib and then add that xib to your controller when you tapped on button.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display the same content every time you click the button, then just add a UIAlert Controller in the IBAction of that button and that should work.